# Jquery serialize with Data Tables makes duplicates

Tags: jquery, forms, serialization

I have a jquery datatable which I'm populating with server side datas.To Data Tables columns are assigned events like (edit, delete). Than I choose one of the row to be edited like clicking on edit button and shows the form in a  modal-box . I edit the element and I save the datas . Next I open another row and I do the same but this time the previously edited datas are getting cached and serialized with the new ones. Firebug shows on send

```
Parameters

action  edit
action  edit
amt 
amt test
au_nr   
au_nr
```

the save event is fired with the following jquery

```
$(document).on('click', '#save', function ( e )  {
    $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: 'action.php',
           data: $("#edit_form_person").serialize(), // serializes the form's elements.               
           success: function(data)
           {
               alert('Data Saved!'); // show response from the php script.           
           },
            error:function(){             
               alert('Error!');                
            }
         });
});
```

**Fixed**

The dialog has to be destroyed on close

```
$(document).on('click', '#form', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();         

    $('<div></div>').load($(this).attr('href')).dialog({
        title: $(this).attr('title'),
        //autoOpen: false,
        modal: true,            
        draggable: true,
        width:900,
        position: ['top',50], 
        close: function(event, ui) 
        { 
            $(this).dialog('destroy').remove()
        } 
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

why don't you clear the form field when the modal opens....i think that should do the trick

```
  $('#formID').find('input[type=text], textarea').val('');
```